# Reset TextView position (scrollable) on new text load

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview

My page loads a TextView which is scrollable. Unfortunately the position appears to stick when loading new text into the view, so Text appears offscreen or invisible entirely. Is there a way to reset the currently "viewed" text to the top?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TextView does have a method inherited from View that you could use, called `scrollTo(x,y)`

so just simply put:

```
myTextView.scrollTo(0,0)
```